# How to create a table based on a query and rows retrieved from select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

i would like to create a table contains the `X`and `Y` values. these values of `X` and `Y`are to be obtaind from the geometry returned from `ST_Envelope`.
i think it should be similar to the following:

```
create table table_name(
    select from ST_X(ST_Envelope(ST_GeomFromText(..))
    )
```

please let me know how to create a table that to be populated with values from select-statement.

Comment: you mean you want to store the x and y from all points in the envelope?

Comment: yes, the x and y  must be the coulmns in the table i am creating and x and y are to be of the same value as of the returned geometry from spatial operation ST_Envelope

Comment: You use `create table table_name as`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ST_DumpPoints` and then `ST_X` and `ST_Y`, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (x numeric, y numeric);

INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT ST_X(geom),ST_Y(geom) FROM (
  SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(ST_Envelope('your_geometry'))).geom
) j (geom);
```

Or if you want to create the table with the exact columns of your query

```
CREATE TABLE table_name AS
SELECT ST_X(geom),ST_Y(geom) FROM (
  SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(ST_Envelope('your_geometry'))).geom
) j (geom);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bb9d4833893590ffd494bdb727d81234)

Comment: hi ..thanks..and if i want to drop it i should replace create with drop key-word..right??

Comment: @LetsamrIt yes, to drop it just run `DROP TABLE table_name`

Comment: can you please tell me despite the table is correctly created, when i try to drop it i receive table "table not existed"

Comment: really? it should work.. see this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=47da7b9a2864e32cb413af7f0084859e

Comment: would you please tell me how to modify the above code in such way that the table if it is existed it should be updated and if it is not existed it should be created

Comment: @LetsamrIt I'm not aware of such SQL command. You can use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (x numeric, y numeric);` and then separately (1st code block in my answer) execute the `INSERT`s

Comment: thanks, but please i want to be able to update the table if it is already created.would you please tell me how?

Comment: @LetsamrIt I'm afraid I don't understand your followup question: by to update the table if exists you mean clean it and repopulate with the new values? notice it is different than an update

Comment: what i ment is, if the table is already existing it the new values must be added to it ..and if the table does not exist it must be created. is it clear now?

Comment: @LetsamrIt check if the table exists when creating the table (`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`) and then execute the `INSERT INTO`... all the time. In case you want to have only the values the last select, place a `TRUNCATE TABLE` between create and insert: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4a1c388fd6f641f2ac2fc9eab58eb4b2

Comment: Hi, maybe you can answer this one as well:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68280325/how-to-combine-inner-join-statement-with-from-clause